# React native TouchableOpacity onPress Problems

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have a simple icon button as follows :

```
class SideIcon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={console.log('puff')} style={styles.burgerButton}>
        <Icon name="bars" style={styles.burgerIcon}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

It's called from the following component :

```
export default test = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isModalOpen: false
    }
  },

  _openModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: true
    });
  },

  _closeModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: false
    });
  },
  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.containerHead} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>
     **<SideIcon openModal={this._openModal} closeModal={this._closeModal} />**
      <Text style={styles.logoName}>DareMe</Text>
      <SideBar isVisible={this.state.isModalOpen} />
     </View>
    );
  }
});
```

But the `onPress`  on the `TouchableOpacity`  never  works. Where I'm going wrong ? Although It shows console statements during the component load.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should bind a function that invokes your code.

For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('puff')} style={styles.burgerButton}>
  <Icon name="bars" style={styles.burgerIcon}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

A better way is to give it a reference to a component function

```
class SideIcon extends Component {
  handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log('puff')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleOnPress} style={styles.burgerButton}>
        <Icon name="bars" style={styles.burgerIcon}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a function, you should pass a fat arrow function to invoke your code.
It should be like this

```
onPress={() => console.log('puff')}
```

Full Example is

```
class SideIcon extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('puff')} style={styles.burgerButton}>
            <Icon name="bars" style={styles.burgerIcon}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
    }
```